# Using google analytics event tracking on 2 pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

Im working on setting up event tracking on a website, the user visits index.php, where he completes a quizz built with javascript, after answering each question i track the event with something like :

```
_gaq.push(['eventTracker._trackEvent', "myCategory", question_number.toString()]);
```

After the user completes the quizz he's redirected to another page : result.php where i track the landing event with :

```
_gaq.push(['eventTracker._trackEvent', 'myResult', myScore.toString()]);
```

The problem is that on analytics i can see the events with category = "myCategory" but not events with category "myResult".

Here is the code (this part is present in both index.php and result.php):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); //an account for tracking page views

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
<script>
     //the account we attach events to
    _gaq.push(['eventTracker._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-3']); 
    //..... racking code as posted before
```